# trouble occurred When I pushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, pushviewcontroller

Recently, a strange question occurred when I pushViewController to the next viewController.
Why I think it's a strange question? because it don't always appears(The probability of occurrence is low). when it appears, next viewController only shows its nav bar on screen, I still can see the rootViewController, but touching it without reaction(PopGesture is effective).Hoping for your help, thanks very much.

[image]

```
#pragram mark - method of pushing   
- (void)clickToAccout {

    if (![self countTotalSelectedNumber]) {
        [SVProgressHUD showInfoWithStatus:@"没有被选择的商品"];
        return;
    }

    CSCreatOrderViewController *creatOrderVC = [[CSCreatOrderViewController alloc] init];
    creatOrderVC.totalPrice = [self countTotalPrice];
    creatOrderVC.goods = [self selectedGoods];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:creatOrderVC animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - chlid class of navgationController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return _barStyle;
}

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
    if (self.viewControllers.count > 0) {
        viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    }

    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - tabBarController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CSTabBar *tabBar = [[CSTabBar alloc] init];
    [self setValue:tabBar forKey:@"tabBar"];

    [self.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor cz_colorWithHex:0Xec5151]];

    [self addChildViewControllerWithTitle:@"首页" imageName:@"home" controllerName:@"CSHomeViewController"];
    [self addChildViewControllerWithTitle:@"分类" imageName:@"classify" controllerName:@"CSClassifyViewController"];
    [self addChildViewControllerWithTitle:@"查询" imageName:@"search" controllerName:@"CSSearchViewController"];
    [self addChildViewControllerWithTitle:@"购物车" imageName:@"cart" controllerName:@"CSShoppingCartViewController"];
    [self addChildViewControllerWithTitle:@"我的" imageName:@"mine" controllerName:@"CSMineViewController"];

    self.selectedIndex = 0;
}

- (void)addChildViewControllerWithTitle:(NSString *)title imageName:(NSString *)imageName controllerName:(NSString *)controllerName {

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(controllerName);

    UIViewController *vc = [[cls alloc] init];
    vc.title = title;
    [vc.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName]]];
    [vc.tabBarItem setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_selected",imageName]]];
    vc.tabBarItem.title = title;

    CSNavigationController *nav = [[CSNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self addChildViewController:nav];
}


#pragma mark - base viewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self setupNavItem];

    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

    _indciatorView = [[CSIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    UIWindow *keyW = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    [keyW addSubview:_indciatorView];

    [_indciatorView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.center.equalTo(keyW);
    }];
}


- (void)setupNavItem {

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(9, 0, 9, 29);
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickToDismiss) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
}

- (void)clickToDismiss {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post within some code?

Comment: ok,waiting a few minutes

Comment: because of this problem can occurred on all my root view controller ,so I suspect that the base view controller has problem, but I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change

```
[super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
```

to

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
```

And the same when pop

```
[super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
```

to

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
```

Comment: where you suspect code is my packaging subclass of UINavgationController, so I think what you said can't solve my problem, but I will try in this direction, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I clear the cache of Xcode, this case don't appear. Maybe I Imported a third lib ago caused this case. But like what I asked ,it don't always appears(The probability of occurrence is low). So, hoping it has been well.

Comment: this issue ocurred again, I'll research it from gesture recognizer